# Import DocType alias in Different language. Umbraco 7.8.1

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I imported a docType from an Umbraco 7.8.1 instance. One of the properties is called "한국 커뮤니티" and its alias is not generating . And even i try to add manual alias but shows error at time of submitting. Or there is any other way to save alias in different language.
please help me to get out of this

[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFWxz.png)

Comment: who on earth uses doctype aliases in Korean? Show us some code on what you've tried, what doesn't work etc. We can't help you like this.

Comment: hello @Jabberwocky i am not using any code. i just want that korean community will add doctype in korean languages this possible  ? and don't know how are using but is my requirement to use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve